# Error when pushing project from Visual Studio - fatal error: value

Tags: git, visual-studio

Unfortunately I didn't find any results belonging to this. It is hard to search with the key word `value`.

So we have a new GitLab server. Pulling a porject works fine, pushing via `git bash` works fine too.

In `VS2022`, when pushing it from the application I'm getting the following error message:

```
Commit 9e3d6886 created locally in repository C:\BL\FAL\...
Pushing master
Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
value
value
Enumerating objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects:  16% (1/6)
...
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects:  16% (1/6)
...
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 672 bytes | 672.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
To https://...
   b90b173..9e3d688 master -> master

Failed to push to the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.
```

In this context I don't know what the term `value` is or means. I am doing a `commit` and then I `push` it.

So I asume the output window is the window named `Output` in `VS2022`. There is no further information what is causing the `fatal error`. The weird thing on this is that the project push is a success, which means, that the project is updated on the GitLab server with a new version.

Hence - because the `push` is successful - maybe the `global config` is causing the `fatal error`? But even there is no word named `value` or an empty variable.